# ValueError: set the `backend` attribute on the user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have added python-social-auth in my project for social logins. I also have a signup form of my own for new users. For social logins, I added some authentication backends.

Now, the social logins are working fine, but the signup form causes some problems.

After I enter the details, and click signup, this error comes up.

I see in the admin panel, the user was added even after this error.

```
ValueError: You have multiple authentication backends configured and therefore must provide the `backend` argument or set the `backend` attribute on the user.
```

Now, it is asking me to set the backend attribute of the user. How to set that ?

Here is the view for signup,

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form  = SignupForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                    raw_pass = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                    user = authenticate(username=username,password=raw_pass)
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('location:get_location')
    else:
            form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form':form})
```

[image]

Comment: It's explained in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login

Comment: @HåkenLid , I did, `user = authenticate(username=username,password=raw_pass, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')`, and now it returned that, `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Instead of doing that, follow the examples in the docs.

Comment: If I do it like that, I am never redirected to the success page, always to the invalid page. Why is it so ?

Comment: Not possible to know from this code alone.  Maybe `location:get_location` is not a valid url name?

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            pass
```